# Bind by clicking on list item like v-model

Tags: vue.js

Currently I have a dropdown component to select language for localization.

```html
<template>
    <div class="localeDropdown">
        <dropdown
            v-model="selectedLocale"
            :items="locales"
            :toggle-label="localeLabels.language"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from '../scripts/store/appConfig';
import { appendQueryString } from '../components/queryUtils.js';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            selectedLocale: '',
        };
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState({
            locales: state => state.locales,
            localeLabels: state => state.localeLabels,
        }),
    },
    watch: {
        selectedLocale(locale) {
            const updatedQueryString = appendQueryString({ locale });

            window.location.search = updatedQueryString;
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Locales:

```js
[
  {"value":"en","label":"English"},
  {"value":"es_mx","label":"Español"},
  {"value":"fr_ca","label":"Français"}
]
```

I'm trying to change the dropdown to a list for mobile in the nav menu.

Here is the list from my nav mobile component:

```html
<ul class="navMobile__list">
    <li
        v-for="(subNavItem, index) in navItem.children"
        :key="index"
        class="navMobile__list__item"
    >
        <a
            :href="subNavItem.url"
            class="navMobile__list__item-link"
        >            
            <span class="navMobile__list__item-label">{{ subNavItem.label }}</span>
            <span
                v-if="subNavItem.isEnabled"
                class="navMobile__list__item-icon-enabled"
            >
                <span class="icon icon--tick">
                    <svg class="icon-inner">
                        <title>Enable</title>
                        <use xlink:href="#tick" />
                    </svg>
                </span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image]
[image]

Currently the dropdown updates the selected language via v-model. Is there a way to get similar functionality from clicking a list item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a `<button>` instead of an `<a>` as the options don't really represent links. In any case, adding a `@click` handler should suffice

```
<li
    v-for="(subNavItem, index) in navItem.children"
    :key="index"
    class="navMobile__list__item"
>
    <button
        class="navMobile__list__item-button"
        @click="selectLanguage(subNavItem.value)"
    >            
        <span class="navMobile__list__item-label">{{ subNavItem.label }}</span>
        <span
            v-if="subNavItem.isEnabled"
            class="navMobile__list__item-icon-enabled"
        >
            <span class="icon icon--tick">
                <svg class="icon-inner">
                    <title>Enable</title>
                    <use xlink:href="#tick" />
                </svg>
            </span>
        </span>
    </button>
</li>
```

Define the click handler in your methods:

```
methods: {
    selectLanguage(value) {
        // Change language to indicated value
    }
}
```